# What is this button (pressed during approach) on the Airbus A320?

Tags: aircraft-systems, cockpit, airbus-a320, feature-identification

I was watching a YouTube video of a cobalt air a320 landing and I seen as he was about 2000 ft AGL he pressed a button on his right hand side just beside the Navigation display. The button illuminated green and 10 seconds later he pressed it again to 'disengage' it.

[image]

Does anyone know what this could be and why it is used?

Answer (score 9):

This is the **TERR ON ND** button, or Terrain on Navigation Display. An [EGPWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_proximity_warning_system) feature that paints the ND screen with the terrain. The color coding indicates if the surrounding terrain would pose a hazard if flown close to. The push button operation is:

[image]

At [46:10 in the video](https://youtu.be/EYj-pT7a-vo?t=2770) the TERR mode was off, the captain turned it on, pointed something out to the first officer, and turned it off. Zurich (the destination) has areas of high terrain around the airport.

[image]
([Source](http://www.fly-sea.com/charts/LSZH.pdf)) Click to view.

#### The color coding and [example](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K3oRKmZ5qQg/maxresdefault.jpg):

[image]
Click to view.